# JPA TypedQuery getResultList() performance is very slow

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jpa, criteriaquery

My code looks like:

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final TypedQuery<ObjectTO> createQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ObjectTO.class);
...
// Logic to create search query
...
// On this line performance is very low. Takes around 200 seconds for 3000 records.
final List<ObjectTO> inhibits = createQuery.getResultList();
```

Generated SQL (example with reduced columns in select clause) looks like:

```
SELECT t1.COL1 ,
    t1.COL2 ,
    t1.COL3 ,
    t2.COL1 ,
    t2.COL2 ,
    t3.COL2 
  FROM Table1 t1
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2,
  ON t1.COL1 = t2.COL1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3
  ON t1.COL1 = t3.COL1
  WHERE (t1.COL2 LIKE 'test')
  AND ( t1.COL3 >= SYSDATE
  OR t1.COL3 = to_Date('1901.01.01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss') )
  ORDER BY t1.COL1 ASC ,
    t1.COL3 ASC ,
    t2.COL2 ASC;
```

Same query when executed in SQL developer, takes around 0.3 seconds. Please note that same query if executed using java.sql.Statement.executeQuery(), takes around 0.4 seconds to fetch data from database. Please note that database is Oracle 11g. JDK version is 1.7.0_51.

JPA entity for Table1 looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long     serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COL1", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String                col1;

    @Column(name = "COL3", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Timestamp             col3;

    @Column(name = "COL2")
    private String                col2;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "col1", cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Table2> table2;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "col1", cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Table3>  table3;

    ...
    ...
}
```

Can you please provide me with an hint regarding where shall I start looking to improve performance in this scenario? Please let me know, if you require more information.

Comment: How many records are you trying to retrieve in a single query? If you don't want all records at once, you can set max results and use pagination accordingly to improve the perforamance. One more important thing is if you don't require the relations to be loaded early, set the fetch type to lazy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes finally decided to go for pagination. Can't change fetch type as both relations are required immediately and wish to avoid multiple network calls to DB.